# TinyEditor - remove instance from page

Tags: javascript, tinyeditor

We're using this script TinyEditor from this [site](http://www.scriptiny.com/2010/02/javascript-wysiwyg-editor/) as a simple WYSIWYG editor for a dashboard we're running.

How do you remove an instance of this editor from the page if you don't need it anymore?

Thanks

Source:
http://www.scriptiny.com/2010/02/javascript-wysiwyg-editor/

Comment: Have you thought about using TinyMCE, it provides more functionality and has many more features and is free. http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

Comment: We have, but decided on this one. Will TinyMCE allow multiple instances?

Comment: yes TinyMCE does allow multiple instances and also allows you enable and disable for each instance of the editor